# Pillow raises error: "AttributeError: read" when attempting to use Image.Open for ImageTk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I am attempting to create a paint program but in my open() function, it raises this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\-------\PycharmProjects\Paint\main.py", line 31, in open
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=Image.open("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Pictures\\dddddd.png")))
  File "C:\Users\-------\PycharmProjects\Paint\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 103, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
  File "C:\Users\-------\PycharmProjects\Paint\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 59, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
  File "C:\Users\-------\PycharmProjects\Paint\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3140, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
  File "C:\Users\-------\PycharmProjects\Paint\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 517, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000002177C9E93F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-------\PycharmProjects\Paint\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 133, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Here is code relevant to the error:

```
def open():
    path = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r", filetypes=[("PNG Image", "*.png")], defaultextension="*.*")
    width, height = Image.open(path.name, mode="r").size
    canvas.config(width=width, height=height)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=Image.open(path.name)))
```

I replaced the "path.name" with a normal path thinking that it may be filedailog.askopenfile isn't providing a proper path although it didn't work. I did double slashes as well, just in case it was using something like "\n".

Comment: `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=Image.open(path.name))` should be `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=path.name)` instead.  However it has another issue that the image will be garbage collected because no one is referencing it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I was using code from a website and haven't used pillow much before.

Comment: That did fix the error, although it still doesn't display the photo.

Comment: It is caused by the garbage collection mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Do you know how to fix the garbage collection issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` option of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` should be a file name or file object, not instance of `Image`.

Also you need to keep the reference of the image, otherwise it will be garbage collected after exiting the function.

It is better to use `askopenfilename()` if you just want a filename. And you have called `Image.open()` twice.

Below is the modified `open()`:

```py
def open():
    # use askopenfilename() instead
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("PNG Image", "*.png")],
                                      defaultextension=".png")
    if path:
        image = Image.open(path)
        width, height = image.size
        tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        canvas.config(width=width, height=height)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=tkimg)
        canvas.image = tkimg # save the reference of image to avoid garbage collection
```

Note also that `open()` is a built-in function of Python, it is better not to use it as your function name.